# What do those writings mean that are on the landing gear doors?

Tags: landing, fighter, jet, gear

I've been watching carrier videos a lot these days and I notice these writings. What do these writings means? I didn't upload all of them, most of the time there are location names and sometimes person names. What is written on those doors? This says UK, this F-18 belongs to US, this is a screen image from a video that was recorded in Naval Air Station Whidbey Island

[image: F-18]

Comment: Bizarrely, thats not How you spell [Bury St Edmunds](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bury+St+Edmunds,+Bury+Saint+Edmunds/@52.2392932,0.6836618,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d81562eecf1ae1:0x2c70565e638e48f9!8m2!3d52.2429228!4d0.7104932)

Answer (score 7):

For a US Navy jet, it is usually the plane captain (who is responsible for checking the plane and making sure it's flight ready) on the landing gear door.

In the image above, the plane captain's rank abbreviation (AE2) and name are on the first line and hometown is underneath.

Comment: You said usually. What else writtens on? Or whose names written on?

Comment: "Usually" just means https://www.blueridgejournal.com/navy/lingo.htm, https://www.quora.com/Why-are-pilots-names-stenciled-on-their-aircraft, and https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/2wjjfm/what_does_it_mean_when_someones_name_is_on_the/ seem to agree that it is the captain, but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-_g3ZMB2kU shows a name that doesn't appear to match. I didn't find any sources that suggested any other name should commonly be found on the gear door.

Comment: AE2 is "Aviation Electrician's Mate Petty Officer 2nd Class", I'm prettttty sure that's not the rank of the captain of this plane...

Comment: @Jpe61 A "plane captain" is ground crew responsible for the aircraft. It is not the same thing as "captain of the plane" or "the plane's captain".

Comment: Oh, sorry, sloppy reading and fast reacting on my part, I somehow managed to misplace the "s" inside my head. My mistake! I should not comment at that hour of day...

Comment: He must be so chuffed that they spelled his hometown of Bury St Edmunds wrong, then! Really raise his confidence in the groundcrew's attention to detail. :-D